# in xslt 2.0, can I import a common xslt file into two files where one outputs xml and the other output html?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm using xslt 2.0.  Can I have a common xslt file that is imported by two main stylesheets, where one of those outputs html and the other outputs xml?

For example, say I have common.xsl.  It transforms xml to xml.

Then I have main_output_xml.xsl.  This will import common.xsl and its output format will be xml.

I also have main_output_html.xsl.  This will also import common.xsl, but it will have an output format of html.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

As Ken Holman says, the answer is yes, you can do exactly what you are suggesting.

@Nalaka526 if your read the question then you will see that it only demands a "yes" or "no" answer. The only reason my answer is longer is that SO doesn't allow short answers.

Answer (score 0):

Short: "Yes".

Long: use named output.

First, define the different [output](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-output) options at the top level of your XSLT.

"20 Serialization.
...
A stylesheet may contain multiple xsl:output declarations and may include or import stylesheet modules that also contain xsl:output declarations. The name of an `xsl:output` declaration is the value of its name attribute, if any."

```
<xsl:output name="text" method="text" indent="no" encoding="utf-8" />
<xsl:output name="default" indent="no" method="html"  encoding="utf-8" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
     doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" />
```

Then use one of the defined `name` methods in your [result-document](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-result-document) output:

```
<xsl:result-document href="output_file.txt" format="text">
...
</xsl:result-document>
```

"19.1 Creating Final Result Trees
...
The `xsl:result-document` instruction defines the URI of the result tree, and may optionally specify the output format to be used for serializing this tree."